# Renewable based Electric vehicle charging station

Tags: battery-charging

I have a solar plant generating 100kw, connected to a boost converter whose output is 500V,what should be my battery nominal voltage and Capacity(Ah) and what can be the maximum current the battery can allow?

Comment: The battery capacity doesn't depend on the things you told us, it depends on what vehicles you'll need to charge during periods when the sun isn't available, how much energy they require, and how many times you might need to charge them.

Comment: @ThePhoton It might also depend upon whether or not the OP wants *any* of that energy poured into the ground and wasted or if the OP wants to capture 100% of what's possible and store it for "next winter." It's not just daily questions. It's seasonal, yearly, willingness to burn off or waste energy when there's no place to put it, etc. I have a simple solution. Just keep buying more electric cars until "all is good." With enough electric cars, time and money, most everything is solvable. ;)

Comment: This appears to be an assignment (which is permissible). BUT you need to show what you've done and what you  understand.  And much more basic information is needed.

Comment: @jonk, if you want to store energy over an annual cycle you might want to invest in a nice pumped hydro reservoir instead of a bunch of expensive batteries.

Comment: I am going to vote to close this because it is kind of unclear what you are really getting at. However, if you add a bunch more information, I will withdraw my vote to close. Is this a homework question? If so, what is your grade level and what is the class? Was any additional information provided? If it is not a homework question, meaning that you really do own a 100kW solar plant, then please hire a consultant to help you.

Answer (score 1):

**given** :

- solar plant generating 100kW,  (assuming best case at MPPT )
- connected to a boost converter whose output is 500V ( assuming at Vmpt )

> What is max load current?

(assuming at max efficiency and max solar input. )

**Answer:** I (max)  = P/V = 100k/0.5kV  = 200 A

**Other info;**

This occurs only when the MPPT output charger impedance Zout= 500V/200A= 2.5 Ohms while the battery ESR is unlikely to match.

The MPPT must regulate to MATCH the impedance at all times and then reduce current   when the battery voltage has been reached CV then cutoff .